# How to merge data frame by picking up selected values based on some logical criteria?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, logical-operators, forecasting

I have 3 data frames with similar structure and i try to fill a 4rth data frame with values from first 3 data frames but on logical condition basis.

My data frame 1

```
`Account id Value $   RMSE
   1          500      10 
   2         7000      15 
   3         1900      20
```

My data frame 2

```
`Account id Value $   RMSE
   1           400      5 
   2          8000     18 
   3          1700     18
```

My data frame 3

```
`Account id Value $   RMSE
   1           500     10 
   2          2000     25 
   3          5000    0.2
```

My desired result is (Value picked up from data frame which has lowest corresponding RMSE)

```
`Account id Value $
  1           400
  2          7000
  3          5000
```

Request your help on how to merge.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your issue you have to bind all your dataframes by row. After that you can use `tidyverse` functions in order to filter by group defined by account id. Here the code with a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
ndf <- do.call(bind_rows,list(df1,df2,df3)) %>%
  group_by(Account.id) %>%
  filter(RMSE==min(RMSE)) %>% select(Account.id,Value) %>%
  arrange(Account.id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Account.id [3]
  Account.id Value
       <int> <int>
1          1   400
2          2  7000
3          3  5000
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df1 <- structure(list(Account.id = 1:3, Value = c(500L, 7000L, 1900L
), RMSE = c(10L, 15L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#Data 2
df2 <- structure(list(Account.id = 1:3, Value = c(400L, 8000L, 1700L
), RMSE = c(5L, 18L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#Data 3
df3 <- structure(list(Account.id = 1:3, Value = c(500L, 2000L, 5000L
), RMSE = c(10, 25, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3))[, .(Value = Value[which.min(RMSE)]), .(Account.id)]
#   Account.id Value
#1:          1   400
#2:          2  7000
#3:          3  5000
```

---

Or with `tidyverse` using `slice_min` after binding the datasets together with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
    group_by(Account.id) %>% 
    slice_min(RMSE) %>% 
    select(-RMSE)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Account.id [3]
#  Account.id Value
#       <int> <int>
#1          1   400
#2          2  7000
#3          3  5000
```

---

```
df1 <- structure(list(Account.id = 1:3, Value = c(500L, 7000L, 1900L
), RMSE = c(10L, 15L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Account.id = 1:3, Value = c(400L, 8000L, 1700L
), RMSE = c(5L, 18L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df3 <- structure(list(Account.id = 1:3, Value = c(500L, 2000L, 5000L
), RMSE = c(10, 25, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option is using `merge` + `aggregate`

```
merge(
  df <- do.call(rbind, lst(df1, df2, df3)),
  aggregate(RMSE ~ Account.id, df, min)
)[c("Account.id","Value")]
```

which gives

```
  Account.id Value
1          1   400
2          2  7000
3          3  5000
```